# What is rc.status file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am creating a linux service , in the skeleton file it is mentioned that we need to run various rc commands(rc-status ,rc_reset) to update the service status. What does this actually mean. I have googled it but not able find many details. Can somebody help me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The commands from rc.status are actually SuSe specific I think. AFAICT they handle two things: output to the user and the final return status of the script. `rc_status` checks if the previous command (i.e. the start/restart/stop of a service) executed successfully and sets the "status value", which is the return value returned by `rc_exit` (which you place at the end of your init.d script). [Source](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Packaging_init_scripts#Exit_Status_Codes)

You can conceivably write your shell script without them, but I assume they help making sure that your script conforms to LSB requirements and blends in well with other system scripts. I bet most of this is actually documented in the `/etc/rc.status` file, though. I just don't have a suse box handy.

Answer (score 2):

You need a shell script to stop/start/restart your service and to give its status.
These are generally called rc scripts.  Have a look in directory /etc/init.d to see some examples - /etc/init.d/klogd is quite a simple one.

The reason they are in init.d is because they also need to be run automatically at boot up to restore the service.

Each Linux variant tends to be a bit different on how the boot up works but the Debian system is fairly typical as it is the basis for many other distributions - see [Debian Boot Up Manager](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bumdocs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the comments block from /etc/init.d/skeleton from SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#     Template SUSE system startup script for example service/daemon FOO
#     Copyright (C) 1995--2005  Kurt Garloff, SUSE / Novell Inc.
#          
#     This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#     under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#     the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at
#     your option) any later version.
#                 
#     This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
#     WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#     MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
#     Lesser General Public License for more details.
#      
#     You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
#     License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
#     Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307,
#     USA.
#
# /etc/init.d/FOO
#   and its symbolic link
# /(usr/)sbin/rcFOO
#
# Template system startup script for some example service/daemon FOO
#
# LSB compatible service control script; see http://www.linuxbase.org/spec/
# 
# Note: This template uses functions rc_XXX defined in /etc/rc.status on
# UnitedLinux/SUSE/Novell based Linux distributions. If you want to base your
# script on this template and ensure that it works on non UL based LSB 
# compliant Linux distributions, you either have to provide the rc.status
# functions from UL or change the script to work without them.
# See skeleton.compat for a template that works with other distros as well.
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          FOO
# Required-Start:    $syslog $remote_fs
# Should-Start:      $time ypbind smtp
# Required-Stop:     $syslog $remote_fs
# Should-Stop:       ypbind smtp
# Default-Start:     3 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 2 6
# Short-Description: FOO XYZ daemon providing ZYX
# Description:       Start FOO to allow XY and provide YZ
#   continued on second line by '#<TAB>'
#   should contain enough info for the runlevel editor
#   to give admin some idea what this service does and
#   what it's needed for ...
#   (The Short-Description should already be a good hint.)
### END INIT INFO
# 
# Any extensions to the keywords given above should be preceeded by 
# X-VendorTag- (X-UnitedLinux- X-SuSE- for us) according to LSB.
# 
# Notes on Required-Start/Should-Start:
# * There are two different issues that are solved by Required-Start
#    and Should-Start
# (a) Hard dependencies: This is used by the runlevel editor to determine
#     which services absolutely need to be started to make the start of
#     this service make sense. Example: nfsserver should have
#     Required-Start: $portmap
#     Also, required services are started before the dependent ones.
#     The runlevel editor will warn about such missing hard dependencies
#     and suggest enabling. During system startup, you may expect an error,
#     if the dependency is not fulfilled.
# (b) Specifying the init script ordering, not real (hard) dependencies.
#     This is needed by insserv to determine which service should be
#     started first (and at a later stage what services can be started
#     in parallel). The tag Should-Start: is used for this.
#     It tells, that if a service is available, it should be started
#     before. If not, never mind.
# * When specifying hard dependencies or ordering requirements, you can 
#   use names of services (contents of their Provides: section)
#   or pseudo names starting with a $. The following ones are available
#   according to LSB (1.1):
#   $local_fs       all local file systems are mounted
#               (most services should need this!)
#   $remote_fs      all remote file systems are mounted
#               (note that /usr may be remote, so
#                many services should Require this!)
#   $syslog         system logging facility up
#   $network        low level networking (eth card, ...)
#   $named          hostname resolution available
#   $netdaemons     all network daemons are running
#   The $netdaemons pseudo service has been removed in LSB 1.2.
#   For now, we still offer it for backward compatibility.
#   These are new (LSB 1.2):
#   $time           the system time has been set correctly  
#   $portmap        SunRPC portmapping service available
#   UnitedLinux extensions:
#   $ALL            indicates that a script should be inserted
#               at the end
# * The services specified in the stop tags 
#   (Required-Stop/Should-Stop)
#   specify which services need to be still running when this service
#   is shut down. Often the entries there are just copies or a subset 
#   from the respective start tag.
# * Should-Start/Stop are now part of LSB as of 2.0,
#   formerly SUSE/Unitedlinux used X-UnitedLinux-Should-Start/-Stop.
#   insserv does support both variants.
# * X-UnitedLinux-Default-Enabled: yes/no is used at installation time
#   (%fillup_and_insserv macro in %post of many RPMs) to specify whether
#   a startup script should default to be enabled after installation.
#   It's not used by insserv.
#
# Note on runlevels:
# 0 - halt/poweroff             6 - reboot
# 1 - single user           2 - multiuser without network exported
# 3 - multiuser w/ network (text mode)  5 - multiuser w/ network and X11 (xdm)
# 
# Note on script names:
# http://www.linuxbase.org/spec/refspecs/LSB_1.3.0/gLSB/gLSB/scrptnames.html
# A registry has been set up to manage the init script namespace.
# http://www.lanana.org/
# Please use the names already registered or register one or use a
# vendor prefix.
#...
# Source LSB init functions
# providing start_daemon, killproc, pidofproc, 
# log_success_msg, log_failure_msg and log_warning_msg.
# This is currently not used by UnitedLinux based distributions and
# not needed for init scripts for UnitedLinux only. If it is used,
# the functions from rc.status should not be sourced or used.
#. /lib/lsb/init-functions
#
# Shell functions sourced from /etc/rc.status:
#      rc_check         check and set local and overall rc status
#      rc_status        check and set local and overall rc status
#      rc_status -v     be verbose in local rc status and clear it afterwards
#      rc_status -v -r  ditto and clear both the local and overall rc status
#      rc_status -s     display "skipped" and exit with status 3
#      rc_status -u     display "unused" and exit with status 3
#      rc_failed        set local and overall rc status to failed
#      rc_failed <num>  set local and overall rc status to <num>
#      rc_reset         clear both the local and overall rc status
#      rc_exit          exit appropriate to overall rc status
#      rc_active        checks whether a service is activated by symlinks
#...
#
# Return values acc. to LSB for all commands but status:
# 0   - success
# 1       - generic or unspecified error
# 2       - invalid or excess argument(s)
# 3       - unimplemented feature (e.g. "reload")
# 4       - user had insufficient privileges
# 5       - program is not installed
# 6       - program is not configured
# 7       - program is not running
# 8--199  - reserved (8--99 LSB, 100--149 distrib, 150--199 appl)
# 
# Note that starting an already running service, stopping
# or restarting a not-running service as well as the restart
# with force-reload (in case signaling is not supported) are
# considered a success.
#...
## Check status with checkproc(8), if process is running
## checkproc will return with exit status 0.
#
# Return value is slightly different for the status command:
# 0 - service up and running
# 1 - service dead, but /var/run/  pid  file exists
# 2 - service dead, but /var/lock/ lock file exists
# 3 - service not running (unused)
# 4 - service status unknown :-(
# 5--199 reserved (5--99 LSB, 100--149 distro, 150--199 appl.)
```

Here is the comments block from /etc/rc.status from SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3:

```
# /etc/rc.status
# vim: syntax=sh
# Definition of boot script return messages
#
#   The bootscripts should use the variables rc_done and rc_failed to
#   report whether they failed or succeeded.  See /etc/init.d/skeleton for
#   an example how the shell functions rc_status and rc_reset are used.
#
#   These functions make use of the variables rc_done and rc_failed;
#   rc_done_up and rc_failed_up are the same as rc_done and rc_failed
#   but contain a terminal code to move up one line before the output
#   of the actual string. (This is particularly useful when the script
#    starts a daemon which produces user output with a newline character)
#
#   The variable rc_reset is used by the master resource control script
#   /etc/init.d/rc to turn off all attributes and switch to the standard
#   character set.
#
#    \033          ascii ESCape
#    \033[<NUM>G   move to column <NUM> (linux console, xterm, not vt100)
#    \033[<NUM>C   move <NUM> columns forward but only upto last column
#    \033[<NUM>D   move <NUM> columns backward but only upto first column
#    \033[<NUM>A   move <NUM> rows up
#    \033[<NUM>B   move <NUM> rows down
#    \033[1m       switch on bold
#    \033[31m      switch on red
#    \033[32m      switch on green
#    \033[33m      switch on yellow
#    \033[m        switch off color/bold
#    \017          exit alternate mode (xterm, vt100, linux console)
#    \033[10m      exit alternate mode (linux console)
#    \015          carriage return (without newline)
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question.